# Comparing two columns with two columns

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a file that I need to compare the values in two columns with another two columns. For examples:

```
Item  A     B     C    D
1    201  3101   3101 201
2   3101   201    202 3101  
3   3101   201    201 3102 
4   3101   201   3202 202
```

So what I trying to do is comparing column *A* & *B* to *C* & *D*, but values in column *A* & *B* and *C* & *D* are interchangeable. And I would like to have a output like *2* if both values are the same, *1* if only one is match and *0* if both are not match. The answer would be something like this

```
Item  A     B     C      D   Output
1    201  3101   3101   201    2
2   3101   201    202  3101    1
3   3101   201    201  3102    1
4   3101   201   3202   202    0
```

How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

This `awk` onliner gets you very close to the desired output (at least the numbers are correct).

```
awk '{n=0} $2==$4 {n=n+1} $2==$5 {n=n+1} $3==$4 {n=n+1} $3==$5 {n=n+1} {print $0, n}' inputfile
```

Basic `awk` is used here. The string between quotes is executed for each line, while the block between brackets is only executed when the statement in front of it is true. `$i` refers to the i-th column.

Comment: if A,B,C,D are identical, output will be 4. i think it's better to merge `$2==$4 {n=n+1} $2==$5 {n=n+1}` to `$2==$4 || $2==$5 {n++}`, and merge `$3==$4 {n=n+1} $3==$5 {n=n+1}` to `$3==$4 || $3==$5 {n++}`

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 True, that would be an alternative. It depends on the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Another `awk` answer, the core part is same. This is a awk script, and more readable

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{ print "Item  A   B   C   D   Output"}
{
    count=0;
    if($2==$4) count+=1;
    if($2==$5) count+=1;
    if($3==$4) count+=1;
    if($3==$5) count+=1;
    if(NR != 1)
        print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" count
}
END{} #Done
```

[Useful Link to awk scripting](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)